# Error with Import Python Packages(Such as Numpy)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am using a compute cluster and dont have access to the entire cluster. Therefore, I am trying to locally(in my "home" directory) install packages for python, but I am having problems with importing them from scripts.

I have tried to update my PATH and my PYTHONPATH, set both to ~/.local/lib. There is already a python 3.7.3 module created on the cluster that I am importing. But I dont have access to it to add more packages to it, which is why I have to install locally. Both the path to the  module and to my .local directory are in the PATH.

When I use pip to install packages, I get this error: "ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/s1/opt/python-3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions." Therefore, I have to install it locally. When I use the `--user` option, everything seems to install fine. Additionally, the python3.7 version in my .local directory only has python and the site-packages directory, while the python3.7 in the module from the cluster has a lot of other files.

After installing these packages, when I go to my scripts and try to run them, I get these errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fragment_assignment.py", line 10, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/s1/snagaraj/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/s1/snagaraj/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 71, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
Here is how to proceed:
- If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
  (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.
- If you are simply trying to use the numpy version that you have installed:
  your installation is broken - please reinstall numpy.
- If you have already reinstalled and that did not fix the problem, then:
  1. Check that you are using the Python you expect (you're using /usr/bin/python),
     and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
     interfere with the Python and numpy versions you're trying to use.
  2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
     https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
     - how you installed Python
     - how you installed numpy
     - your operating system
     - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
     - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log

     Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
     an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.
```

Original error was:

> No module named _multiarray_umath

As a side note, all the fixes proposed to others who had the error that I found did not work for me.

Comment: Are you able to `pip install --user pipenv` or `pip install --user virtualenv virtualenvwrapper`? The first one ([`pipenv`](https://docs.pipenv.org/en/latest/)) will probably be easiest.

Comment: I am able to run the first command(with pipenv).

Comment: Hi! If you have the reputation to do so, and one of the answers helped, please [upvote it and mark it as correct](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). This lets others visiting the site with your question know what worked with as little extra digging as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest creating a [virtual environment](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/) for your application/development needs and then running in that. In general, virtual environments are a great way to make sure you have all the dependencies you need and do not have a bunch of conflicting issues with other things. Probably the easiest way to get going is with [`pipenv`](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/). [Another article on virtual environments and pipenv](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/).

To start, make sure `pipenv` is installed:

```
$ pip install --user pipenv
```

Create a folder for your project and change directory into it (or just `cd` into your current project directory):

```
$ mkdir my_project
$ cd my_project
```

And then start installing the packages you will need from within your `my_project` directory:

```
$ pipenv install numpy scipy pandas
```

or whatever packages you need. Once that operation finishes, you activate your environment by running:

```
$ pipenv shell
```

and then whatever you want to do with python. Alternatively, you can just run a script (we'll call it `my_script.py`) in the environment with:

```
$ pipenv run python my_script.py
```

Comment: If I move my existing directory, (that houses Test Data, scripts, and more), into a new directory that is created with this pipenv virtual environment, would that cause any problems?

Comment: You can just do the `pipenv install` commands inside your current project directory instead. It's just important that you have a directory in which your pipenv will be active.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Virtual environments changed my life. It's a good habit to get into. Please upvote and mark as accepted when you have enough reputation to do so.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there may be a missing dependency somewhere. Try installing `libatlas3-base` to get that file.

```
sudo apt-get install libatlas3-base
```